# Fetching ALL data from Table with Where AND OR

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to this forum. I hope I will be able to explain my question to everyone.

I want to call the data from columns (WareParkOut or/and EndKm) with specific user. But the query I am using in my session is showing the data from other user id's too

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        from tblleaves 
        where empid=:eid 
        AND WareParkIn = '' 
        or EndKm = '' 
        order by PostingDate desc";
```

I am finding it hard to use AND or operators here which I believe is the problem.

AS a result, I want to call everything from table tblleaves in every customer login if WareParkIn is empty or EndKM is empty or both are empty. But it is showing all customers empty data in every login. I want it login specific.

e.g User ID 1's login is showing other users WareParkIn or EndKM too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tblleaves 
        where empid=:eid 
        AND (WareParkIn = '' or EndKm = '') 
        order by PostingDate desc";
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer is downvoted most likely because off missing explainment or answering a duplicated question.. As the topicstarters problem indeed seams to be operator precedence

Comment: I didn't understand either. Better if I remove this answer?

Comment: I don't think the answer is incorrect. I assumed it was downvoted for the same reasons @RaymondNijland said.